# Why does my ggplot have the wrong y-axis scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using a concatenated version of frankbi's Price of weed data (https://github.com/frankbi/price-of-weed for the original, https://github.com/Travis-Barton/Github_code for the cleaned version). I turn the histograms of HighQ/MedQ/Lowq into density lines. Then I try to plot those density lines on top of one another in a ggplot environment, but my axes are coming out all wrong.

This is what I should have:
[image: Good Plot]

This is what I end up getting:
[image: Bad Plot]

Why is ggplot scaling my x-axis? Below is my code

```
dat <- marijuana.street.price.clean



hist(dat$HighQ)
hist(dat$MedQ)
hist(dat$LowQ)

plot(1, ylim = c(0, .02), xlim = c(0, 800))
lines(density(dat$HighQ), lwd = 3, col = 'green', lty = 2)
lines(density(dat$MedQ), lwd = 3, col = 'yellow', lty = 2)
lines(density(dat$LowQ, na.rm = T), lwd = 3, col = 'red', lty = 2)


dat2 <- data.frame(indexH = density(dat$LowQ, na.rm = T)$x,
                   propH = density(dat$HighQ)$y,
                   indexM = density(dat$MedQ)$x,
                   propM = density(dat$MedQ)$y,
                   indexL = density(dat$LowQ, na.rm = T)$x,
                   propL = density(dat$LowQ, na.rm = T)$y
                   )

ggplot(dat2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = propH, x = indexH, colour = "High")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = propL, x= indexL, colour = "Low")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = propM, x = indexM, colour = "Medium"))
```

Comment: You err here `indexH = density(dat$LowQ, na.rm = T)$x`. It should be `indexH = density(dat$HighQ, na.rm = T)$x`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! @Darren